# Existence of tesserane and it's properties

Tags: carbon-allotropes

Could there exist an allotrope of carbon, $\ce{C16}$ where the overall shape of the molecule is a three dimensional representation of a tesseract? And what are its (predicted if unknown/unsynthesised) properties if it does? I imagine this molecule would be highly strained, but I don't know if it shares a stability comparative to cubane's.
The only predicted properties I could find were [chemicalize's](http://chemicalize.com/) calculations that it has a high solubility in water, of approximately 1200 mg/ml, and a polarizability of $\ce{17.83 A^3}$ (which has little meaning to me as I don't know typical values of polarizability).

Comment: I doubt such a compound is possible. It would seem to require making a much larger version of cubane that could fit cubane inside of it. Any arrangement large enough for that to occur would be too large for the outer carbon vertices to be bound to each other.

Comment: Could alkyne moieties make up the outside?